# Use two different delimiters in "qw" in Perl language?

Tags: perl, delimiter

On the page 47 of the book **Learning Perl: Making Easy Things Easy and Hard Things Possible**, there is

> Sometimes the two delimiters can be different. If the opening delimiter is one of
> those “left” characters, the corresponding “right” character is the proper closing
> delimiter:

[image]

But, it doesn't display any case in which there are two different delimiters in **pw**. So, what is the meaning of **the two delimiters can be different**? Could you make an example and explain it?

I just don't know the meaning.

Comment: It displays **four** examples of them being different right under the paragraph you highlighted. `(` and `)` are different. `{` and `}` are different. And so on.

Comment: @Quentin  Okay. I mistakenly thought that the left and right delimiters could be different.

Comment: @Y.zeng Don’t edit the question into a different question.

Comment: @Biffen  Okay. But I can't post a new one now.

Comment: `"undef"` produces the string `undef`. Use `undef` to produce an undefined value.

Comment: @ikegami But the `undef` doesn't have quotes. In this situation, the `undef` is a string?

Comment: Re "*But the `undef` doesn't have quotes.*", Yes it did (`("flintstone","rubble","undef")`). Or do you mean in the output? Why do you expect `print` to add quotes?

Comment: @ikegami It is `("flintstone","rubble",undef)`, it doesn't have quotes here, not refers to the output.

Comment: That's not the code you posted, and `("flintstone","rubble",undef)` doesn't produce the output you said you obtained.

Comment: @ikegami  Yes. You are right. So, how should I know whether it is `undef`?

Comment: Most uses of `undef` will warn. You can also check if a value is undef using `defined` or `//`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever the opening delimiter is `{`, `[`, `<` or `(`, the closing delimiter is the matching closing bracket, and thus different than the opening delimiter.

Examples using paired delimiters:

- `qw{...}`
- `qw[...]`
- `qw<...>`
- `qw(...)`

This list is exhaustive without the experimental [`extra_paired_delimiters` feature](https://metacpan.org/pod/feature#The-%27extra_paired_delimiters%27-feature).

For all other opening delimiters, the closing delimiter is the same as the opening delimiter.

Examples using same delimiter:

- `qw/.../`
- `qw!...!`
- `qw}...}`
- etc

---

Tip: When using paired delimiters, you can nest them without escaping. For example, `qw( foo(s) bar(s) )` is valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So in the book, the different delimiters refers to the paired delimiters, am I right? May you tell me how did you know that "When using paired delimiters, you can nest them without escaping. "?

Comment: [Quote-like operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-Like-Operators) are documented in [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop). It's a very long section, and the relevant bit is in the "Gory details of parsing quoted constructs" subsection.

Comment: Okay. It is too difficult for me to read now. I will read it again in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> two delimiters can be different

This doesn't mean "two delimiters can be any two random characters that you want". It actually means "in four specific cases, the closing character can be the reversed version of the opening character".